# How to close DaisyUI drawer menu with just one click?

Tags: svelte, daisyui

I'm using the DaisyUI drawer component to render a menu on mobile. See here for a working example:
https://daisyui.com/components/drawer

Now in the example there's a button which can be used to open and close the mobile menu.

The button triggers a checked status on following checkbox to show/hide the drawer:

```
<input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle">
```

My code:

```
let checked = 'checked';

function handleClick() {
    (checked == 'checked') ? checked = '': checked = 'checked';
}
```

On the input:

```
<input id="my-drawer-3" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" bind:checked={checked}>
```

On the menu item:

```
<a on:click={handleClick} href='/test'>Test</a>
```

The problem is that I have to click two times to hide the drawer. The first click triggers a visual effect on the menu item. The second click closes the drawer. How can I achive the same result with just one click?

**DEMO Link:**
https://svelte.dev/repl/c06f018ac84f4b86b1d37f7576d25db1?version=3.29.7

Comment: Could you please provide a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1)?

Comment: To start with: svelte checkbox binding return true or false.  docs: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/checkbox-inputs

Comment: Hmm difficult. On TailwindPlay I can't add svelte and and on REPL I can't add TailwindCSS with DaisyUI. Have to fiddle this out...

Comment: @voscausa the binding from my code is working so far. I think I have to skip the visual effect somehow in order the checked state gets set immediately not requirering another click.

Comment: You can import daisyUI/tailwind in the REPL in a `svelte:head` [like this](https://svelte.dev/repl/0a285ee88f474578833e8b1c9abe79bc?version=3.29.7)?

Comment: @Corrl thanks for your link! Very helpful. I've added a demo link to the description text.

Answer (score 8):

Just add this to your `<a>` tag

```
<a on:click={() => {document.getElementById('my-drawer-3').click()}} href='/test'>Test</a>
```

Comment: Your solution just solved this very DaisyUI drawer problem I've been facing since last night. The problem was that the drawer wouldn't close upon navigating to different routes, nether would the dropdown or buttons unfocus. So I fetched all links, and triggered on click events on them to remove their focus. Within this was where I now placed the return value above which helped to finally close the drawer. Thanks a lot. (DaisyUI with React).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but the variable 'checked' should be a boolean. Your logic could work because a '' string is falsy, but it would be best to rule that out.

```js
let checked = false;
const handleClick = () =>{
  checked = !checked;
}
```