# DaisyUI - How to close the drawer?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, daisyui

I'm using SvelteKit with a drawer from [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/components/drawer/).

```html
<div class="drawer lg:drawer-open">
  <input id="my-drawer-2" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
  <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <label for="my-drawer-2" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button lg:hidden">Open drawer</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="drawer-side">
    <label for="my-drawer-2" class="drawer-overlay"></label> 
    <ul class="menu p-4 w-80 h-full bg-base-200 text-base-content">
      <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='/my-page'>My page</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the drawer to close when I click on one of the `<a>` tag.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70744177/12066144) suggests using `on:click`:

```html
<a on:click={() => {document.getElementById('my-drawer-3').click()}} href='/test'>Test</a>
```

But doing so doesn't work in this scenario:

1. Have a screen wide enough to display the drawer all the time.
2. Click on an item
3. Reduce the width of the screen to hit the breakpoint when the drawer would hide.

In this scenario, the drawer remains open.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it. It works for me!

```
<svelte:head>   
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@1.16.2/dist/full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</svelte:head>

<script>
    let checked = '';

    function handleClick() {
        (checked == 'checked') ? checked = '': checked = 'checked';
        console.log(checked)
    }
</script>


<div class="rounded-lg shadow bg-base-200 drawer h-52">
  <input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" bind:checked={checked}> 
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center drawer-content">
    <label for="my-drawer" class="btn btn-primary drawer-button">open menu</label>
  </div> 
  <div class="drawer-side">
    <label for="my-drawer" class="drawer-overlay"></label> 
    <ul class="menu p-4 overflow-y-auto w-80 bg-base-100 text-base-content">
      <li>
        <a href='/'>Home</a>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <a href='/my-page'>My page</a>
      </li>
        <li>
            <button on:click={() => {checked = ''}}>Close</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't include a `lg:drawer-open`. Also, I want the drawer do close when I click on the `<a =href='/'>` (for example). I'm not trying to have another button for that